# How to store an output from a UNIX command into a char with in C programming

Tags: c, unix

Let's say here is my code:

```
int main() {
    char *number;
    system("grep total myfile > filename");

    printf(number);
}
```

This code finds the line from myfile containing "total" and outputs it into a new file called filename.  I am trying to have the output set to the char "number" directly, instead of having to write/read from filename.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure how that can possibly work. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a user input to set the value of `number`, or do you want to read the file `filename` and set the value of `number` accordingly?

Comment: By formatting your command into a character array, rather than hard-coding it. In this case, you could just `open` filename and write it in there yourself, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand right your title, you want get the `output` from the `command` executed,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()  {
    char number[100];
    FILE *f = popen("echo 200", "r");
    while (fgets(number, 100, f) != NULL) {
        printf( "%s\n", number );
    }
    pclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Or do you simply just want to pass variable into the command AND output your variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()  {
    int n = 100;
    char buf[100];
    sprintf(buf, "echo %d > filename", n); // format the command
    system(buf);                           // execute
    printf("%d\n", n);                     // print the variable

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks. fixed. Interesting thing is the original version worked.  So I just copy-and-paste.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  But i need to use "system("fgrep total filename | cut -f5 -d' ' > filename2")" to grab the 5th word in the line containing "total" and set that to a string.  I am not sure how to incorporate that into your code example.  Do i just replace the "system(buf)"?

Comment: try the `popen` version, put your command string there, and see what the output is.

Comment: BTW, if you put `> filename2` in the command, you will NOT get anything.  Because outputs have been redirected to the `filename2`, in that case, you have to open the `filename2` to get the output.  You may want to remove the `> filename2` from your command, get the output from the `popen` and process and output to `filename2`.

Comment: I tried 
FILE *f = popen(system("fgrep total filename | cut -f5 -d' '"), "r");
but it gives me two errors: "Integral value implicitly converted to pointer in assignment." and "Argument #1 is not the correct type."

Comment: @DaveWang The first parameter to `popen` should be a string. You have `system(...)` as the first parameter, just use `popen("fgrep ...", "r")` without `system`.

Comment: really? the only thing i changed from your code was FILE *f = popen(system("fgrep total filename | cut -f5 -d' '"), "r");

Comment: @DaveWang see OlafDietsche's reply. I didn't notice you passed `system` to `popen`:P

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way, since you're writing a file, is to open and read the file.  You could do that like this:

```
char number[100];
FILE *fp;

system( "echo 200 > filename" );
fp = fopen( "filename", "r" );
if( fp != NULL ) {
    if( fgets(number, 100, fp) != NULL ) {
        printf( "%s\n", number );
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

If you don't want to write/read the file, you can do a little dance with forking your process, opening pipes and using `exec`, and reading the data straight out of the process you ran.  There's bound to be a question on SO about that already.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help.  I was actually trying to store the output from the system command to a char directly, with out having to write/read the file.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See the other answers about using `popen`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly what you meant, that is not the way to go.

Take a look at [pipe](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) and [dup2](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_dup2.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to start your subprocess

```
FILE *fp = popen("echo 200", "r");
if (fp != NULL) {
    char number[20];
    if (fgets(number, sizeof(number), fp))
        printf("%s\n", number);

    pclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sprintf()` function to pre-create string with the necessary number and then just call system(your_string).

[sprintf() examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)